# Cannot control servos through 32-servo-controller on Aurduino Duamilanove

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, servo

I have servo (TowerPro sg90) connected to 32 servo controller ([this one](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Version-32-Channel-Robot-Servo-Control-Board-Servo-Motor-Controller-PS2-Wireless-Control-USB-UART/32272674301.html)) through UART interface (RX-TX, GND-GND). 
Seller provide documentation how to connect and control my servos, but it isn't work.

Servo work if I connect it indirectly to Arduino. Controller indicate that it is working too (photo below - red led).

I already try different servos. Also try use provided software to control servos from pc through Mac/PC. But it's interface is unreadable for me. I tried different options but servos not responding.

Sketch code below (from sellers examples):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("#3P500T2000\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("#3P1500T2000\r\n");
  delay(3000);
  Serial.print("#3P2500T2000\r\n"); 
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("#3P1500T2000\r\n");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Photo of my connections:

[image: arduino-duamilanovo+32-servo-controller+servo]

Sorry if it post duplicate some, but I cannot google this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't place for such question. I will ask it again on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as you stated you should ask this else where... but if this is  your entire setup you need to add power to the servo controller.  Do not try to control a bunch of servos off of a USB port or though the arduino regulator... if you are lucky you will just cause the computer USB to go into a protected state... if you are not lucky you will burn out the USB port.

Comment: @MatthewWhited you are absolutely right. I asked on arduino.stackexchange and got advice about power supply. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I answer my own question because it's remain unanswered and confuse people.

SO isn't a place for such questions. I got an answer [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18279/cannot-control-servos-through-32-servo-controller-on-aurduino-duamilanove).

Answer (score 2):

First, an advise: DO NOT EVER USE A SERVO DIRECTLY IN YOUR ARDUINO, your lucky it haven't burn. Now to the answer... You need to external power your servo controller. See the especifications of your servo and provide it the correct voltage.

Comment: Here, if you need more information about this kind of board: http://letsmakerobots.com/files/32_Servo_Controller_Manual.pdf                        It's not the same you have, but the usage is very similar

Comment: Sorry for my unclear words about "directly connection". I use additional board for servo connection (do not remember it's name). I'll try your manual tonight and accept if it help. Thank you.